# ajax popup lightbox doesn't show styling when in active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am using [lightcase](http://cornel.bopp-art.com/lightcase/#demo) plugin to show my ajax content but when it shows it doesn't have any styling images are broken . In inspect element i do not find styling css on each elements . But when i am using magnific popup it works . But main problem with magnific popup is it doesn't works with setTimeout() function . Is there any solution of that two problem?

Comment: Can you show us fiddle or some code ?

Comment: make sure you have referenced the css file in header, show us your code to assist you better